# Error: call of overloaded 'stoi(nlohmann::basic_json<>::value_type&)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, json

I'm using the Json for modern C++ project [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). I met with the following problem. The `obj_json` is a json object and I want to get the value of `obj_json["key"][0][1]`, which shall be an integer value. Therefore I wrote:

```
int id;
id = obj_json["key"][0][1];
```

I met with the error saying:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::domain_error'
  what():  type must be number, but is string
```

So I change the code to:

```
int id;
id = std::stoi(obj_json["key"][0][1]);
```

I get the following error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'stoi(nlohmann::basic_json<>::value_type&)' is ambiguous
In file included from /home/mypath/gcc-5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/string:52:0,
             from /home/mypath/gcc-5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/stdexcept:39,
             from /home/mypath/gcc-5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/array:38,
             from ../json-develop/src/json.hpp:33,
             from libnba.cpp:1:
/home/mypath/gcc-5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/bits/basic_string.h:5258:3: note: candidate: int std::__cxx11::stoi(const string&, std::size_t*, int)
   stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
   ^
/home/mypath/gcc-5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/bits/basic_string.h:5361:3: note: candidate: int std::__cxx11::stoi(const wstring&, std::size_t*, int)
   stoi(const wstring& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
```

I'm confused with this. As shown in the first error message, the `obj_json["key"][0][1]` is a `string`. But in the second error message, why does the error happens?
I also print out the type of the object, using the following code:

```
cout << typeid(obj_json["key"][0][1]).name() << endl;
```

The type printed is

```
N8nlohmann10basic_jsonISt3mapSt6vectorNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEblmdSaEE
```

I'm totally confused...
How to solve this?
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: After the "call of overloaded" error there should be a list of viable functions.  Please edit your question to add them.

Comment: @aschepler I have added all the error messages. Thank you.

Comment: try `std::stoi(std::string(obj_json["key"][0][1]))` , the error message indicates that json result can either be converted to `string` or `wstring` so you have to choose. There's probably a  member function you could use instead of the explicit cast (if you're in an IDE, hit `.` after the `[1]` and see what comes up)

Comment: @M.M Thank you. But it causes new errors, the error message is similar to what I presented, "error: call of overloaded 'basic_string(nlohmann::basic_json<>::value_type&)' is ambiguous"

Comment: Ok, look for member functions instead. This is the problem with allowing lots of implicit conversion operators...  Another angle of attack might be to read the documentation and look for examples

Comment: @M.M You mean read the documentation of the json project?

Comment: Of the nlohmann::json library that you are using

Comment: @user31264 obj_json["key"][0] is a list of strings. obj_json["key"] is list of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `obj_json["key"][0][1]` is not a string. Its type is: `nlohmann::basic_json<>::value_type` . You should look for the library, and check what is the `nlohmann::basic_json<>::value_type`, and how to convert it to number.

Answer (score 3):

I find an answer that seems helpful [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/144). In the answers of this issue, someone said `basic_json` can convert to both a `char` and a `std::string`, which made the compiler did not know the type of an object. I don't know whether this is the reason for my own problem. But the following solution works for me:

```
int id;
str temp_str_val;
temp_str_val = obj_json["key"][0][1];
id = stoi(temp_str_val);
```

That is, declare a `string` variable and copy the value to it first. Then call `stoi` on the `string` variable.
This only makes my code work, but does not answer my question that why this happens.
I'm still looking forward to better solutions.
Thank you all for helping me!